# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:pthread_create(1040kb stack) failed: Out of memory

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa5rC.png)
only happend in android-5.1.1 -lollipop
I can't reproduce this crash.
this bug was catched by bugly

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701501/throwing-outofmemoryerror-pthread-create-1040kb-stack-failed-try-again-when

Comment: add android:largeHeap=true in manifest

Answer (score 2):

You can set `android:largeHeap="true"` in application tag of Menifest file. But this is not proper way. It is good if you can find some memory leak in your app. Try to check for memory leak in your app and then resolve it. Some asynktasks may produce memory leak in you app or passing context may also produce memory leak.

[This link](http://www.theshiftingbit.com/Fixing-Memory-Leaks-in-Android-Studio) may help you to find memory leak in your application.