# How to determine where OutOfMemory occurred on android?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I get an `OutOfMemoryError` in my app:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11746
Process: kr.co.iosystem.blackeyeonandroid, PID: 1618
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1337)
at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.addConnection(ConnectionPool.java:208)
at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.recycle(ConnectionPool.java:198)
at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.recycle(OkHttpClient.java:111)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$AbstractSource.endOfInput(HttpConnection.java:377)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:426)
at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:349)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request.onLoad(PollingXHR.java:292)
at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request.access$600(PollingXHR.java:135)
at com.github.nkzawa.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$Request$1.run(PollingXHR.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I check my log but I don't know where the outofmemory occurs in my source.

How to fix the outofmemory problem?

Comment: Try moving all the heavy images from `drawable` folder to `drawable-nodpi` folder. Check this [link](https://medium.com/@oronno/android-drawable-outofmemoryerror-ebe2995760b6)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46401786/3395198

Answer (score 0):

You have to find where you are doing memory intensive tasks. You have to avoid memory leaks also.
You can use a library to track memory leaks.
https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Answer (score -1):

In your manifest application section add following below

```
       android:largeHeap="true">
```

This is the temporary solution you have to find out the real causes and solve

Comment: Sir , `largeHeap` is not good solutions .

Comment: thanks, @IntelliJAmiya  What is a good solution?

Comment: @hyunwooks kindly check https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: trace your memory using https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html docs

Comment: already my app use `android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: Are you sure this outofmemory is a bitmap problem?

Comment: are you using volley to call webservice?

Comment: @vishaljangid  not use volley , but I use http protocol, because get public ip

Comment: may be you are creating request object on every hit of service call. like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701501/throwing-outofmemoryerror-pthread-create-1040kb-stack-failed-try-again-when

Answer (score -1):

**Use android:largeHeap="true" to solve this**

Check that the image size is smaller than the available memory before attempting to load it. So the most efficient way to handle OutOfMemoryException is to architecture your application in such a way that it never attempts to load lots of data into memory in order to avoid the exception.

Comment: I don't think that `allowBackup` will be helpful here, neither `largeHeap`. Although I agree with the fact that you need to have a good architecture that doesn't use too many resources at the same time. Also, an app leaks free is what you should try to achieve  since from my experience these caused most of the crashes.

Comment: @Geeta Gupta    I know `android:allowBackup="true"` is set auto backup option.    why you set `allowBackup` manifest my source?

Comment: `android:allowBackup="true"` wrong point .