# Having OutOfMemory Error while installing APK via USB or direct using setup in my project

Tags: android

please help me out as per before 2-3 days project working very well but now when i try to install(Run) project in device than it shows some error like this:::

```
09-25 14:35:06.618 6990-6990/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.xiaomi.gamecenter.exportdbcache
09-25 14:35:06.618 6990-6990/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.xiaomi.gamecenter.miui.recommend
09-25 14:35:07.168 6990-6990/? E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 291316636 byte allocation with 4410740 free bytes and 89MB until OOM"
09-25 14:35:07.218 6990-6990/? E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 291316636 byte allocation with 4410692 free bytes and 89MB until OOM"
09-25 14:35:07.248 6990-6990/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.android.packageinstaller, PID: 6990
     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 291316636 byte allocation with 4410692 free bytes and 89MB until OOM
         at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:612)
         at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
         at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2872)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2573)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2468)
         at com.miui.internal.variable.v21.Android_Content_Res_Resources_class.handleLoadDrawable(SourceFile:40)
         at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:834)
         at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:799)
         at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageUtil.getAppSnippet(PackageUtil.java:167)
         at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity.onCreate(PackageInstallerActivity.java:659)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6039)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1315)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
```

Here is my menifiest.xml

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:name=".utils.MainApplication"
     android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/main_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/main_logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">.............
</application>
```

Comment: Its a `OutOfMemoryError` problem

Comment: so how can i resolve this ?@IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @Mr.Mad; By using images that are not 277 MB

Comment: even there is I'm using total 1.7Mb Images  @0xDEADC0DE

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 291316636 byte
>   allocation with 4410692 free bytes and 89MB until OOM

**[OutOfMemoryError](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html)**

> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because
>   it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the
>   garbage collector.

An image with a higher resolution does not provide any visible benefit, but still takes up precious memory and incurs additional performance overhead due to additional on the fly scaling.

**Common Problem**

- When you are dealing with large Bitmap and load all of them at run
  time.

**Common Solutions**

- Reduce Image size .

Read [**`Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap)